# Session storage preferences in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, session, memcached

I have a node.js application that uses a MySQL database. I wanted to know what would be a good place for storing the sessions?

My application is actually a final project for one of my courses, but it could be a real world application later, as we are re-writing a software that is currently used by the university. I can use MySQL for session store, but I want to make my application using the most reliable or best practice in my situation.

I have read many posts/answers/forums, and the opinion is divided. Using another technology like Memcached/MemcacheDB or Redis, just for session store, would it be a recommended approach? Or should I just stick to MySQL, and later deal with scaling if the server load increases?

Even if the application is later used in real world, it would only be used by the undergraduate university students and faculties, so the users are sort of limited.

As of now, I'm leaning towards MySQL for the session store.

Answer (score 1):

I am replying under the assumption that you are using MySQL throughout the whole application.

If the application will be used in the context of your university possibly it will not have scaling issues. SQL databases are not bad, they are able to handle quite a lot of data efficiently, you just need to be careful in the first place and to create efficient queries. Be careful with the joins because can really kill the server. You need to analyze quite a lot your application. For example, why do you think that you will have scaling/performance issues on the sessions and not in another place of your application? Do a bit of load testing, get some metrics and try to understand if you need it or no.

If you are a student though and you don't have prior experience with redis, I would go with redis because it is good to work with a new technology and gain a bit more of experience :)

Comment: Did you mean using Redis for the entire application or just the sessions? Yes, I'm a student and haven't used Redis. Also, I'm using the sequelize ORM and wouldn't have any joins as I try to avoid them.

Comment: @Silencer310 Redis just for the sessions!